# How to save files in ngrx store?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Since last week I have migrated my app to ngrx. Now I'm facing a problem: My app needs access to File objects the whole time my app runs. Because ngrx stores JSON objects only, it can't store File objects and other type of classes.

What is the best way to handle File objects using ngrx? Do I have to convert them to JSON objects and save them to the store or do I have to save them out of the store? Or is there any other way?

Context: the app does audio processing and makes use of other text files.

For further processing I need the contents of the file, its name and size. I thought about making a JSON object, but this could be inefficient (because ngrx creates copies of its state):

```
{
  name: string;
  size: number;
  buffer: ArrayBuffer;
}
```

Comment: If you have particular example, that will help answering your question better. But if you are looking for high level answer then its effect where you handle.

Comment: it's difficult to create an example, because my application is too big. That's why I'm asking in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrx can store File objects just like any other service. Because the redux plugin for the browser can't output the File object correctly I thought File objects are not supported by ngrx. If I output the current state to the console the list of files is available as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Saving files, async calls, localStorage/ sessionStorage etc are handled as side effects.

Look into [Ngrx Effect](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) documentation.

You should translate files or other complex objects into JSON and store in the store.

Comment: with "saving files" I mean saving them as File[] array, not saving them to the hard disk. Or did I misunderstand your answer?